# Wysihtml5 brokes modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

If i use wysihtml5 in modal, when i open modal with form that use wyshtml5 it works fine first time. But when i close modal, and then open it second time then wysihtml5 funtionality not working it shows only text area not toolbox and iframe. if i close the model and it open again it working file as first time. and fourth time same issue arise.in other word wysihtml5 working alternatively in bootstrap modal.It's wysihtml5 bug, or i`m doing something bad?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {      
    $('#description').wysihtml5();
});

<div class="modal-body">         
<div class="alert alert-danger error_block" style="display: none"></div>
<form action="#" id="post_updt" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    <h4>Title <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></h4>
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Title" id="post_title" name="post_title" class="col-md-12 form-control" required="true" value="">
                </div><label id="post_title-error" class="help-block help-block-error" for="post_title"></label>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group post_description">
        <label class="control-label">
            <h4>Description</h4>
        </label>
        <div class="controls"> 
            <textarea id="description" name="description" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group event_dates hide">
        <label class="control-label">
            <h4>Event Dates <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></h4>
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Event Dates" id="event_dates" name="event_dates" class="col-md-12 form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#post_type").change();      
    $('#description').wysihtml5();
});

$("#post_type").on('change', function () {
    var vl = $(this).val();
    $("#file_url").removeAttr("required");
    if (vl == 'Event') {
        $(".event_dates").removeClass("hide");
        $(".upld_document,.post_description").addClass("hide");
    } else if (vl == 'Document') {
        if($("#old_file").val()==""){
            $("#file_url").attr("required","true");
        }
        $(".upld_document").removeClass("hide");
        $(".post_description,.event_dates").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $(".upld_document,.post_description").removeClass("hide");
        $(".event_dates").addClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a bug. When you use wysihtml5 in modal, you should initialize it on modal shown and you should remove it on modal disappear.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('#modal_Event').on('shown', function () {
        $('#description').wysihtml5();
    });

    $('#modal_Event').on('hidden', function () {
        $('.wysihtml5-sandbox, .wysihtml5-toolbar').remove();
        $('#description').show();//optional
    });

});
```